# Filter out tuples with only one element

Tags: python, tuples, networkx

I have a tuple containing coordinates for a list of nodes. The process I am attempting to complete needs a tuple with only 2-tuple or 3-tuples. I am trying to filter out any 1-tuples.

```
G=nx.read_shp(r'C:\TestData\tl_2019_36013_roads.shp')
pos = {k: v for k,v in enumerate(G.nodes())}
X=nx.Graph() #Empty graph
X.add_nodes_from(pos.keys()) #Add nodes preserving coordinates
edg=[tuple(k for k,v in pos.items() if v in sl) for sl in l]
print(edg)
```

A portion of this output is:

```
[(38, 9848), (40, 41), (40,), (10, 42)]
```

So in this case, I am attempting to filter out the entry: (40,) as it is only a 1-tuple.

Comment: `[t for t in tuples if len(t) > 1]`

Comment: `edg = [t for sl in l if len(t:=tuple(k for k,v in pos.items() if v in sl)) > 1]`

Comment: but maybe two passes would be more clear

Answer (score 1):

I guess the fastest and most pythonic way to filter this input is to use filter :)

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, input_list)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
tuplelist = (40,), (40,21), (532, 234)
newlist = []
for i in tuplelist:
    if len(i) != 1:
        newlist.append(i)
```

using the len function, you can check if the length is not 1
you can also do this:

```
tuplelist = (40,), (40,21), (532, 234)
newlist = []
[newlist.append(i) for i in tuplelist if len(i) != 1]
```

Comment: do **not** use list comprehensions for side-effects!

Comment: Using a list comprehension to append to an existing list is like going shopping, then throwing out the groceries you just bought so you can keep the bags. Instead, just... buy some bags. (Or in other words, use the list comprehension for the new list it creates.)